# How can you check the value of an attribute an source of an image using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a condition that checks the attribute for a particular value and the source of an image. If both values both match true, then do something.

So far I have:

```
if ($('meta[content="New Reviews"]').length > 0) && ($( "img[src*='default-label']" ) {

  //Do something

}
```

Not sure if this is written correctly but I believe I wrote the syntax wrong.

Comment: Use same logic and check length i.e. `$('meta[content="New Reviews"]').length && $( "img[src*='default-label']" ).length `

Comment: @Satpal Thanks this solution also works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure your parentheses match, and that you check `length` for both collections:

```js
if ($('meta[content="New Reviews"]').length && $('img[src*="default-label"]').length) {
  console.log('Found!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta content="New Reviews" />
<img src="default-label/image.png" />
```

Comment: This is a great solution!